# How to find the proc name for `GetProcAddress` function using WinDbg

Tags: c++, windbg, getprocaddress

I want to use `GetProcAddress` to get some functions addresses inside a loaded DLL. I run some attempts on PSAPI library and I can see the the expected proc name is not identical to the symbol names I find with WinDbg `x` statements. For example, I look for "EnumProcessModules"(which is the name expected by `GetProcAddress` method) with `x psapi!*EnumProcessModules*` and I find

```
00007ff9`fe112210 PSAPI!_imp_K32EnumProcessModulesEx = <no type information>
00007ff9`fe111360 PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesExStub (<no parameter info>)
00007ff9`fe111030 PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesStub (<no parameter info>)
00007ff9`fe1121a8 PSAPI!_imp_K32EnumProcessModules = <no type information>
```

When I provide any of the found symbols above (with or without "PSAPI!" as a prefix) to the `GetProcAddress` method as the second parameter (procName) -  it returns NULL, but when I use the method name "EnumProcessModules" - it returns 0xfe111030, which is the address of "PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesStub".

How could I know the expected `procName` in advance? What if I have 2 different classes or namespaces with the same method name in one DLL? How can I distinguish between the two method names when I call `GetProcAddress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PSAPI!` is just a prefix, it's the DLL name printed by WinDbg. That's used to disambiguate names. A clear example why this is useful: you will have many `DllMain`'s in your process.

The expected name for `GetProcAddress` is the **documented** name of the function, as stated on MSDN. Keep in mind that you will need to add either the `A` or `W` suffix when MSDN states both versions are available. E.g. you can't call `GetProcAddress` with `"GetDeviceDriverFileName"`, you need either `"GetDeviceDriverFileNameA"` or `L"GetDeviceDriverFileNameW"`.

For non-system DLL's, you need the function name from the Export Address Table.

Background: What you see in WinDbg is the name from the .PDB, which as you have discovered can differ from the exported name. There is nothing which enforces a relation between the two. For instance, it's technically possible to have PDB names `Foo` and `Bar`, and have them swapped in the Export Address Table. More realistically, Microsoft may internally add an `_wrapper_EnumProcessModules` at any time, but the documented and exported name will stay `EnumProcessModules`.

Answer (score 0):

The Core Functionality for this API is implemented in **kernel32.dll** 
and Named **K32EnumProcessModules**

in paspi.h header this API is ifdeffed based on PSAPI_VERSION

```
#ifndef PSAPI_VERSION
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN7)
#define PSAPI_VERSION 2
#else
#define PSAPI_VERSION 1
#endif
#endif

#if (PSAPI_VERSION > 1)
#define EnumProcessModules          K32EnumProcessModules
```

if you GetProcAddress in psapi.dll you get a stub which gets transferred to kernel32.dll

```
0:001> u PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesStub l 5
PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesStub:
762d1408 8bff            mov     edi,edi
762d140a 55              push    ebp
762d140b 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
762d140d 5d              pop     ebp
762d140e eb05            jmp     PSAPI!K32EnumProcessModules (762d1415)

0:001> u 762d1415 l1
PSAPI!K32EnumProcessModules:
762d1415 ff2504102d76    jmp     dword ptr [PSAPI!_imp__K32EnumProcessModules (762d1004)]

0:001> u poi(762d1004) l1
kernel32!K32EnumProcessModules:
7668cc52 8bff            mov     edi,edi
```

you can use dumpbin /exports on the dll to see if there is any correlation 
or if there is a name change (see the Stub@16 )

```
:\>dumpbin /exports c:\windows\System32\psapi.dll | grep -w EnumProcessModules
          5    4 00001408 EnumProcessModules = _EnumProcessModulesStub@16
```

you could also find the same info from the export table of psapi.dll using some thing like below

```
0:001> .shell -ci "!dh psapi" grep Export
    1088 [     359] address [size] of Export Directory
.shell: Process exited
0:001> dt ole32!_IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY  (psapi + 1088)
   +0x000 Characteristics  : 0
   +0x004 TimeDateStamp    : 0x4a5bc026
   +0x008 MajorVersion     : 0
   +0x00a MinorVersion     : 0
   +0x00c Name             : 0x11be
   +0x010 Base             : 1
   +0x014 NumberOfFunctions : 0x1b
   +0x018 NumberOfNames    : 0x1b
   +0x01c AddressOfFunctions : 0x10b0
   +0x020 AddressOfNames   : 0x111c
   +0x024 AddressOfNameOrdinals : 0x1188
0:001> r? $t0 = (int *) @@(psapi + 10b0)
0:001> r? $t1 = (int *) @@(psapi + 111c)
0:001> r? $t2 = (short *) @@(psapi + 1188)
0:001> .printf "%x %ma %y\n" , @@(@$t2[4]) , (@@(@$t1[4]) + psapi) , (@@(@$t0[4]) + psapi)
4 EnumProcessModules PSAPI!EnumProcessModulesStub (762d1408)
```